# VSCode client-server document sync

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

**Subject:**

My extension provides AutoCompletion, Hover, Definition and so on based on some data, that depends on document content and current cursor position. In large documents it takes a lot of time to compute this data for all providers. So I decided to split the extension in client and server.

I've done this:

```
import * as server from 'vscode-languageserver';
var connection = server.createConnection();
var documents = new server.TextDocuments();

connection.onInitialize((params: server.InitializeParams) =>
{
    return {
        capabilities: {
            textDocumentSync: documents.syncKind,
            completionProvider: {
                resolveProvider: false
            }
        }
    };
});

documents.listen(connection);
connection.listen();
```

**Question:**

How can I get actual document content and current cursor position both at the same time at server side?

When I try to get current document on completion request

```
connection.onCompletion(context =>
{
    let document = documents.get(context.textDocument.uri);
    console.log(document.getText().length);
    return [];
})
```

I find out that it's not changing

The same happens on `connection.onDidChangeTextDocument` event.
I can get new document content through `event.contentChanges[0].text` if 
`textDocumentSync` in `connection.onInitialize` is set to `server.TextDocumentSyncKind.Full`, but in this way the `event.contentChanges[0].range` field is undefined.

**How can I deal with it?**

Any examples or helpful documentation appreciated

Comment: "I find out that it's not changing" - could you be more specific what you mean by that?

Comment: I meant that the document content (text) doesn't change (or I've got it in wrong way) on server when typing in the editor.

Comment: Hm.. it seems to behave as expected for me if I modify the `onCompletion()` callback in the official lsp-sample. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/e0257ec013d4eb69a1947b1ab0c1aef184920d58/lsp-sample/server/src/server.ts#L177

Comment: Ok, I've found out something interesting:
uncomment `connection.onDidChangeTextDocument` in this example and try to check it again. There will be no changes in document on server.

btw, there is some more, that I can't understand: it's behavior depends on if `connection.onDidChangeTextDocument` is **before**
`documents.listen(connection);`
`connection.listen();`
or **after**